# Is there any WebM libvpx .Net wrapper?

Tags: c#, wrapper, webm, libvpx

Is there any [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) [libvpx](http://www.webmproject.org/code/) .Net wrapper to encode for example video created frame by frame from your C# code? (I know that in theory it can be done using DS filters but I do not want to mess with it..)